# Is possible to implement Facebook login from localhost with v3.2 version API?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

As I followed a number of URLs to fix the error but didn't work for me.

I am facing error to implement facebook login from localhost with `API version v3.2`

Kindly let me know if we can implement facebook login from localhost, If yes, then what should be configuration values for the web from localhost?

**Error Message -**

> **Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the App's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings**.

After put **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** value **showing one more error.**

> Error - URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is
>   not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client
>   and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

**Application configuration-**

```
**App domains - localhost
Valid OAuth Redirect URIs - https://localhost/
Privacy Policy URL - http://gmail.com/
Site URL - https://localhost:443/CodeIgniter-3.1.9/**
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: first of all facebook login api need https it will not work on http.

Comment: what is API version v3.2

Comment: @PHPGeek, It's API facebook API version. Select APP->Setting->Advance setting->Upgrade API Version.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, Yes I have install SSL on localhost And it's running on https://localhost, For private policy URL i tried with https://gmail.com but still facing same error.

Comment: `localhost` is not a domain that has any meaning outside the machine it is running on. If your development server has a publicly accessible ip address that points to the web server you might be able to use that instead.

Comment: @DFriend, Thank you for your suggestion, As of now, I was working on local machine. But now, I will deploy the same on public IP. Thank you.

Comment: You system does not need to be publicly reachable to be able to test login, since all the relevant stuff (redirects) happens in the user’s browser. // Your Valid OAuth Redirect URI most likely is not what you have specified. Check the address bar when the login dialog/that error message is shown - the _exact_ value of the `redirect_uri` parameter needs to be specified in the app settings.

Comment: We have whitelisted localhost as a special case so you may use http on localhost only.

Comment: @misorude, Thank you for your suggestion. It solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) server for running your local server into cloud server. After running the ngrok server, you will get a url like https://12345.ngrok.io. Set it as App domain in facebook.

Comment: Waww.. This is a good solution to work on https or without domain name or without public IP. Thank you for suggestion.